# Code works on console application but not on ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pdf, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to create reports in my ASP.NET MVC 5 application. I found this code (Hello world example in http://report.sourceforge.net/):

```
    Report report = new Report(new PdfFormatter());
    FontDef fd = new FontDef(report, "Helvetica");
    FontProp fp = new FontPropMM(fd, 25);
    Page page = new Page(report);
    page.AddCB_MM(80, new RepString(fp, "Hello World!"));
    RT.ViewPDF(report, "HelloWorld.pdf");
```

When I put this code inside a main in a console application, it creates and opens a PDF file that writes "Hello World".
But when I put the same code inside a controller in ASP.NET like this, I get nothing, no PDF opens or no PDF is saved in the server (I click mywebsite/Person/Print) :

```
 public ActionResult Print(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Person person= db.Person.Find(id);
        if (person== null)
        {

            Report report = new Report(new PdfFormatter());
            FontDef fd = new FontDef(report, "Helvetica");
            FontProp fp = new FontPropMM(fd, 25);
            Page page = new Page(report);
            page.AddCB_MM(80, new RepString(fp, "Hello World!"));
            RT.ViewPDF(report, "HelloWorld.pdf");
        }
        return View(person);
    }
```

How can I modify my ASP.NET application to let user get PDFs using this code? (I will also appreciate if you know any cool-free reporting tools for ASP.NET MVC 5.) Thanks.

Comment: We have no information on Report class. Where is it coming from? What library is it?

Comment: You'll have to change the approach you're taking completely. When running a console app, the output will be rendered on the running machine and shown as per usual. But a web site or service computes on the server and returns results to the client, so the interaction model is completely different. You'll have to allow the user to download the pdf by serving it as a downloadable resource over http/s, either by generating them on the fly and returning the `File` or generating them on the server and serving the client with a link to the resource.

Comment: @Sphaso I added the link about the library.

Comment: You seem to be using the Console Application and `RT.ViewPDF` starts Adobe Reader. Which for obvious reason won't work on a server environment. But that Library seems horribly outdated (last releases in 2004 and 2006)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what libraries you are using there but the general flow of your action should be like:

- prepare report object
- obtain byte array representing the content of the PDF file
- return a File from your action using the File method: [Controller.File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.file%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

The result on the client would be a file download prompt